# Multicolumn sort without having two columns (or more) highlighted with PrimeNG

Tags: angular, sorting, primeng

I can sort multiple columns while using a `p-table` with PrimeNG as following :

```
[multiSortMeta]="[{field: 'quantity', order: -1}, {field: 'price', order: 1}]"
```

```
<h3>Multi Sort Columns</h3>
<p-table
  [columns]="cols"
  [value]="cars1"
  [lazy]="lazy"
  [lazyLoadOnInit]="lazyLoadOnInit"
    (onLazyLoad)="loadList($event)"
  [sortMode]="sortMode"
  [multiSortMeta]="[{field: 'quantity', order: -1}, {field: 'price', order: 1}]">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Yet, having two columns highlighted by default can be confusing. How can I have a default sort for two columns, yet only highlight the primary column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you want to sort your data by `quantity` and `price` but only show `quantity` indicator in the table.

First, sort your data returned by your service by `price`:

```
this.productService.getProductsSmall().then(data => {
  this.products2 = data.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
});
```

or if you want the reverse order:

```
this.productService.getProductsSmall().then(data => {
  this.products2 = data.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
});
```

Then, replace

```
[multiSortMeta]="[{field: 'quantity', order: -1}, {field: 'price', order: 1}]"
```

with

```
[multiSortMeta]="[{field: 'quantity', order: -1}]"
```

to show only `quantity` indicator.

It should to what you need.

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesort-demo-gb9apr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: From my understanding, I believe that, there is no other way to do this, without js.